# Does National visistor center affect all cities?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

The description for National visitor center says:

> Must have built a Hotel in all Cities. The cost goes up the more cities there are in the empire. 100% of the Culture from World Wonders, Natural Wonders, and Improvements (Landmarks, Moai, Chateau) is added to the Tourism output of the city. Tourism output from Great Works +100%.

Does this mean that this wonder gives this bonus for all cities or just the one it is built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect only applies to the city where the center is build, so it's best to build it in the city with the most wonders and culture producing sites.

[Source: Civilization wikia](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/National_Visitor_Center_(Civ5))